# LinearLayout cannot be cast to a class I've created

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

My exception: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to dismo.ufrj.br.bradmobile.HeaderClass

I've created a class, HeaderClass, that extends LinearLayout. But I cant seem to cast it the right way.(header is a linearlayout)

Here's the code

```
    headerClass = (HeaderClass) findViewById(R.id.header);
```

Comment: Post the entire relevant code

Comment: You need to specify your custom View class in the layout, not a LinearLayout.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is exactly stated in the error message: Your layout contains a `LinearLayout`, and you attempt to cast it to your own class. You can't do that. Instead, you will need to change the xml to read:

```
<dismo.ufrj.br.bradmobile.HeaderClass
    ....
    ....
    .... >

  ....

</dismo.ufrj.br.bradmobile.HeaderClass>
```

Inheritance doesn't matter much here, but since your `HeaderClass` extends `LinearLayout`, you could cast the above xml to a `LinearLayout` in code.

Comment: You've got an extra `/`.

Comment: @MikeM., indeed I did. Fixed.